# SwiftUI: Align subviews one by one from different stacks

Tags: swiftui

I would like to align the views of two HStacks **one by one**. This means:

- The first text of the first stack is aligned with the first text of the second stack.
- The second text of the first stack is aligned with the second text of the second stack.
- The third text of the first stack is aligned with the third text of the second stack.

I need to have the two HStacks, because I have to apply styling to the them horizontally.

I have tried using layout guides, but it will just align each whole HStack to the layout guide, so it does not work in my case.

Playground screenshot:

[image]

Playground code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let alignmentGuide = HorizontalAlignment(
        HorizontalAlignment.CustomAlignment.self
    )
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: self.alignmentGuide, spacing: 20) {
            topHstack
                .background(Color.gray)
            bottomHstack
                .background(Color.gray)
        }
        
    }
    
    var topHstack: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("1 top")
                .alignmentGuide(self.alignmentGuide) { $0[.leading] }
            Text("2 top")
            Text("3 top")
        }
    }
    
    var bottomHstack: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("1 bottom")
                .alignmentGuide(self.alignmentGuide) { $0[.leading] }
            Text("2 bottom")
            Text("3 bottom")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


extension HorizontalAlignment {
    
    struct CustomAlignment: AlignmentID {
        static func defaultValue(in context: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
            context[HorizontalAlignment.leading]
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Edit:
I can use a `LazyVGrid` to fix the alignment, but then I can not style the rows.

```
 var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.flexible()),GridItem(.flexible()),GridItem(.flexible())], alignment: .leading) {
            Text("1 top")
                .alignmentGuide(self.alignmentGuide) { $0[.leading]}
            Text("2 top")
            Text("3 top")
            
            Text("1 bottom")
                .alignmentGuide(self.alignmentGuide) { $0[.leading] }
            Text("2 bottom")
                .alignmentGuide(.leading) { $0[.leading] + 20 }
            Text("3 bottom")
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

    }
```

Comment: Try one of the Grid Views

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up using a grid and a background view to style the first row, since this is all that I needed.

In case one has a dynamic number of rows, calculating the frames for the background view might become trickier, but I have not found another way of doing it.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var heightOverlay = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.flexible()),GridItem(.flexible()),GridItem(.flexible())], alignment: .leading) {
            Group {
                Text("1 top")
                Text("2 top")
                Text("3 top")
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 10)
            .background(GeometryReader { reader in
                Color.clear.preference(key: HeightPreferenceKey.self, value: reader.size.height)
            })
            Text("1 bottom")
            Text("2 bottom")
            Text("3 bottom")
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .onPreferenceChange(HeightPreferenceKey.self) { preference in
                self.heightOverlay = preference
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
            .background(Color.red.frame(height: self.heightOverlay), alignment: .top)
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct HeightPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat = .zero
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value = max(value, nextValue())
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it is not oversimplified example of real code in the question, then a possible solution can be quite simple - just simulate some kind of regular grid inside `HStack` (yes, it is limited, but sometimes be enough, and even correct behaves with `.fixedSize`)

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

```
extension Text {
    func wideLeading() -> some View {
        self.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            topHstack
                .background(Color.gray)
            bottomHstack
                .background(Color.gray)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
    }

    var topHstack: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("1 top").wideLeading()
            Text("2 top").wideLeading()
            Text("3 top").wideLeading()
        }
    }

    var bottomHstack: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("1 bottom").wideLeading()
            Text("2 bottom").wideLeading()
            Text("3 bottom").wideLeading()
        }
    }
}
```